# Java Generics: Unknown wildcards e T

Tags: java, genéricos

Pude verificar que em Java podemos utilizar tanto um unknown wildcard ("?"), quanto o "T" (como isso se chama?) para criar mecanismos genéricos (classes, métodos, interfaces...). Mas não ficou claro para mim quais são as principais diferenças entre esses artifícios e quando devo utilizar um ou outro. Alguém poderia ajudar, por favor?

Answer (score 4):

Por convenção, `T` é usado para representar um *type parameter*, ou **parâmetro de tipo**, usado na declaração de uma classe genérica.

Como já mencionado na resposta do Jean, existe uma convenção para casos mais comuns, embora você possa usar qualquer letra na prática.

Um exemplo clássico é a declaração da classe `List`, que representa uma lista de elementos. Portanto temos:

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> { ... }
```

Na hora de usar a lista, podemos então definir o tipo `E` da lista, assim:

```
List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<>();
```

E agora o compilador vai avisar se tentarmos colocar qualquer coisa que não seja uma `String` na lista.

Só que às vezes queremos explicitamente deixar uma lista sem um tipo definido. Isso poderia ser feito apenas com `List`, mas nesse caso o compilador vai pensar que você esqueceu de declarar o tipo.

Para isso usamos o *wildcard* `?`, como no exemplo:

```
int contar(List<?> qualquerTipo) {
    return qualquerTipo.size();
}
```

Note que eu não precisa saber o tipo para contar os elementos da lista, portanto é um uso perfeitamente válido.

Existem outras aplicações para isto, mas geralmente é um tipo de meta-programação genérica usada em frameworks ou rotinas utilitárias onde o tipo real não importa.

Isso não deve ser usado com frequência nas implementações de sistemas que fazemos no dia-a-dia, já que é bem mais insegura.

Answer (score 3):

Em primeiro lugar, `T` pode muito bem ser substituído por `E` ou `Z` ou `TYPE`. É apenas o nome dado ao parâmetro de tipo genérico.

Na maioria das vezes, as letras seguintes escolhido por convenção :

- `K` para "**K**ey", exemplo : [`Map<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)
- `V` para "**V**alue", exemplo : [`Map<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)
- `E` para "**E**lement", exemplo : [`List<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
- `T` para "**T**ype", exemplo : [`Collections#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-)

Note que para `T` deve ser visto como *classe* em vez do *typo*, desde por definição, todas elas representam um tipo qualquer maneira.

---

Sobre *wildcards*, ele não pode ser usado em una declaração. Isso só pode ser utilizado em contexto genérico (entre `<>`) quando não conhece o tipo.

Exemplos :

```
public <?> ? foo(? bar) //não irá compilar.

public <T> T foo(T bar) //ele irá compilar.

public foo(List<?> bar) //ele irá compilar.
```